# Will ref callbacks always be invoked in the order they are declared in render()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So far, I haven't been able to track down documentation or React source that answers this question. For the following React component ...

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    divRefs = [];

    addRef = (node) => {
        if (node) {
            this.divRefs.push(node.id);
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div id="node1" ref={ this.addRef }>one</div>
                <div id="node2" ref={ this.addRef }>two</div>
                <div id="node3" ref={ this.addRef }>three</div>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

... will the order of ids in the `divRefs` array consistently follow the order that the divs are included in the render declaration? (i.e. the ref callbacks are invoked in an identical order as render) The resulting array looks like this, but can I reliably expect this result, in this order? Why or why not?

```js
...
console.log(this.divRefs); // ['node1', 'node2', 'node3']
...
```

Comment: Not related to your problem (*most probably*), but still may I ask you: what's the purpose of using Refs in your particular use case?

Comment: I'm working on some form validation, and performant solutions for that always rely on direct DOM access (see also react-hook-form, Formik, etc). I'm figuring out how I want to maintain references to refs.

Comment: *'...performant solutions ...always rely on direct DOM access'* Really? To me, extracting DOM node properties and then validating them looks way more awkward, and seems to be slow compared to validating state variables (that correspond to input values) right away. I don't even mention that form validation [does not fall](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs) into any recommended Refs use cases.

Comment: Controlled inputs (e.g. redux-form) cause tons of re-renders, and don't offer as much flexibility for a wide variety of form UIs. Controlled inputs aren't really an option given the needs where I work. Furthermore, we're trying to strike a balance between developer experience and providing consistent behavior and tooling for a wide variety of form UIs. We've found, as other libraries have, that this requires direct DOM access.

Comment: Did you actually measure the performance of your app?

Answer (score 0):

You get [following](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) guarantee for callback refs:

> React will **call the ref callback** with the DOM element **when the component mounts**, and call it with null when it unmounts. Refs are guaranteed to be up-to-date before componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate fires.

Now the question is, in which [order](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10204#issuecomment-316077434) are the children mounted:

> it is up to React to decide in which order to actually call their render functions

So, there seems to be no 100% guarantee, that children are consistently rendered, mounted and ref callbacks invoked corresponding to their order in `render` code. To be safe, you can instead update `divRefs` directly via indices, which are passed to `addRef`:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    divRefs = [];

    addRef = (node, index) => {
        if (node) {
            this.divRefs[index] = node.id
            console.log(`Set node ${node.id}`, JSON.stringify(this.divRefs))
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div id="node1" ref={ n => this.addRef(n, 0) }>one</div>
                <div id="node2" ref={ n => this.addRef(n, 1) }>two</div>
                <div id="node3" ref={ n => this.addRef(n, 2) }>three</div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.1/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-vMEjoeSlzpWvres5mDlxmSKxx6jAmDNY4zCt712YCI0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-QQt6MpTdAD0DiPLhqhzVyPs1flIdstR4/R7x4GqCvZ4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

This also avoids stale entries caused by `push`, when a ref is dropped and then re-added to a DOM node. Alternatively, create an array of nodes and map over them to get rid of manual indices:

```
// render()
const nodes = [{ id: "node1", label: "one" }, { id: "node2", label: "two" }];
return nodes.map((n, idx) => (
    <div id={n.id} key={n.id} ref={n => this.addRef(n, idx)}> {n.label} </div>
));
```